# Running as a cron job failing to get output

Tags: linux, cassandra, cron, cassandra-3.0

When I execute below script it runs fine and I get the results in email. But when I run it as a cron job its sending 0 number of agents.

I have a below scrip t(countagentid.sh)..

```bash
if [ -e /home/countagentid.csv ]
then
    rm -rf /home/countagentid.csv
fi

cqlsh -f countagentid.cql `hostname -I`  -u cassandra -p password -- (countagentid.cql has cql statment which will generate the output of cql query and save in csv format)
OUTPUT="$(cat /home/countagentid.csv |sort|uniq|wc -l)" --I sort & get the distinct values of the csv and assign it to $OUTPUT variable 
clustername=`cat /etc/cassandra/conf/cassandra.yaml |grep cluster_name |cut -f2 -d :`
mailalert(){
/sbin/sendmail -F Cassandra -it <<END_MESSAGE
To: test@gmail.com
Subject: Number of  agents in Cassandra $clustername

$OUTPUT  Number of  agents.
END_MESSAGE
}
mailalert
```

Answer (score 0):

put the script on other path.

Run below command and share output logs.

sh -x script_name.sh

Gautam Sheladiya